# LaTeX Over Leaf Awesome CV - Space between entries

Tags: overleaf, awesome-cv, vspace

[image]

I want to remove the space between Company name and Title as show in the picture. Unable to remove space in `\cventry` using `\vspace`

```
    \cvsection{Experience}
     \begin{cventries}
     \cventry
{Game Developer Intern at Global Internship Program}
{NEXON}
{Seoul, S.Korea \& LA, U.S.A}
{Jan. 2013 - Feb. 2013}
{
  \begin{cvitems}
    \item {Developed in Cocos2d-x an action puzzle game(Dragon Buster) targeting U.S. market. Implemented API server which is communicating with game client and In-App Store, along with two other team members who wrote the game logic, designed game graphics.}
    \item {Won the 2nd prize in final evaluation.}
  \end{cvitems}
}
```

Comment: You have been taken in by a common misconception.  What is referred to on the internet as “LaTeX templates” are in reality other people's documents which are tailored to their specific needs.  Therefore it is **close to impossible** to perform any modifications on these without breaking the entire thing.  They are really only meant to exchange their content with yours.  Any other adjustment is simply out of scope.

Comment: If my answer was helpful for you please consider upvoting and accepting it! That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help"!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `awesome-cv.cls` and search for the `\cventry` macro.  Then you can insert a negative inter-row space.  I chose `-2pt` (see the marked line).

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\[-2pt] % <--
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{G#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

[Live example on Overleaf](https://v1.overleaf.com/read/hynjvfbwmzkp)

Answer (score 1):

Please add an MWE (minimal working example) to your questions!  For now I use my code from your last question ...

In your case here you need to redefine command `\cventry` in your preamble of your cv code:

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[5]{% <=========================================
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\[-5pt] % <=================================
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{G#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

See both important lines marked with `<=========`.  Change the value of `[-5pt]` for your needs ...

So with the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter
%\usepackage{multicol}
\geometry{%
  showframe,
  left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm
} % Configure page margins with geometry
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parallel}


% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-skyblue} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[5]{% <=========================================
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\[-5pt] % <=================================
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{G#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{James}{Bond}
\mobile{(+01) 234 56789}

\email{test@example.com}

\makecvfooter{\today}{James Bond~~~--~~~Curriculum Vitae}{\thepage}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CV/RESUME CONTENT
%   Each section is imported separately, open each file in turn to modify content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsection{Education}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cventries}

%------------------------------------------------
\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something else} % Degree
{University} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}

\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
\cventry
{Game Developer Intern at Global Internship Program}
{NEXON}
{Seoul, S.Korea \& LA, U.S.A}
{Jan. 2013 - Feb. 2013}
{
  \begin{cvitems}
    \item {Developed in Cocos2d-x an action puzzle game(Dragon Buster) targeting U.S. market. Implemented API server which is communicating with game client and In-App Store, along with two other team members who wrote the game logic, designed game graphics.}
    \item {Won the 2nd prize in final evaluation.}
  \end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsection{Technical Skills}
  \begin{cvskills}
    \cvskill
      {Programming Languages:}
      {Java, Python, C, C++, R, JavaScript}
     \cvskill
       {Web Technologies:}  
        {HTML5, CSS3, XML, AngularJS, PHP, JSON, Ajax, .Net}
     \cvskill
        {Databases:}  
        {Oracle 12c, SQL, MySQL, MongoDB}
      \cvskill
         {Platforms/Tools:}  
         {Amazon EC2, Docker, Linux, Eclipse, Visual Studio, GIT}
     \end{cvskills}

\cvsection{Skills}
{ % start group for font
% \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont
  \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\bodyfontlight\color{text}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1 text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 2 text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 3 text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
        \item item 6
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
} % end group

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image]